# Is there way to specify axis limits on a chart through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, visualization

This is what I'm trying to work with rn but the syntax I'm using doesn't adjust the limits for the axes, I've tried multiple other types of syntax I found online but I'm lost.. idk why the chart isn't able to pick up the minimum/maximum function.

```
Sub JigsFeStat():
Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xData As Range
    Dim yData As Range
    Dim xData2 As Range
    Dim yData2 As Range
    Dim xData3 As Range
    Dim yData3 As Range
    Dim xData4 As Range
    Dim yData4 As Range
    Dim xData5 As Range
    Dim yData5 As Range
    Dim xData6 As Range
    Dim yData6 As Range
    Dim xData7 As Range
    Dim yData7 As Range
    Dim serName As Range
    Dim InitialDate As Variant
    Dim FinalDate As Variant
    
     Set xData = Range("Dates")
     Set yData = Range("JigsFe")
     
     Set xData2 = Range("Dates")
     Set yData2 = Range("JigsFe1")
     
     Set xData3 = Range("Dates")
     Set yData3 = Range("JigsFe2")
     
     Set xData4 = Range("Dates")
     Set yData4 = Range("JigsFe3")
     
     Set xData5 = Range("Dates")
     Set yData5 = Range("JigsFe4")
     
     Set xData6 = Range("Dates")
     Set yData6 = Range("JigsFe5")
     
     Set xData7 = Range("Dates")
     Set yData7 = Range("JigsFe6")
     
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Sheets("Report")
    
    Dim chtObj As ChartObject
    Set chtObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Width:=470, Height:=182, Left:=Range("A156").Left, Top:=Range("A156").Top)
    
    With chtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MinimumScale = 20
        .MaximumScale = 80
    End With
    
    
    ' chtObj.Chart.ChartStyle = 23
    
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = chtObj.Chart
    
    Dim ser As Series
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    
    cht.HasLegend = True
    cht.HasTitle = True
    cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Jigs - Fe%"
    
    cht.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    
    ser.Values = yData
    ser.XValues = xData
    ser.Name = "Jigs-Fe%"
    ser.ChartType = xlXYScatter
   
    Dim ser2 As Series
    Set ser2 = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ser2.Values = yData2
    ser2.XValues = xData2
    ser2.ChartType = xlLine
    ser2.Name = "UCL"
    
    Dim ser3 As Series
    Set ser3 = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ser3.Values = yData3
    ser3.XValues = xData3
    ser3.ChartType = xlLine
    ser3.Name = "LCL"
    
    Dim ser4 As Series
    Set ser4 = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ser4.Values = yData4
    ser4.XValues = xData4
    ser4.ChartType = xlLine
    ser4.Name = "2s"
    
    
End Sub
```

If someone can help identify why the max/min function isn't working in this case I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Tried it but I'm still getting an error, "Method "MinimumScale" of object "Axis" failed."

Comment: Then, try moving the sequence of setting the scales at the end of the code. Just before `End Sub`. I mean, `With chtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue)`
       `.MinimumScale = 20`
        `.MaximumScale = 80`
    `End With`

Comment: The Macro Recorder should do this for you.Turn on the Recorder, click through the steps you need to click, and the recorder should automatically generate all the code you need.

Comment: It actually worked putting at the end before End Sub @FaneDuru, I don't really understand how the placement affects it like that but I appreciate it

Comment: When you add series, Excel guesses/calculates which is the best min/max ratio according to the input range **and use it**. Without caring about the initial settings. If you set them at the end it is obliged to do as the code states...